# why doesn't ctrl+d exit ghci in emacs shell ... but does exit for the python REPL?

Tags: python, shell, emacs, ghci, control-characters

When using the emacs `shell` buffer, the `control-d` keystroke doesn't exit from the `ghci` REPL but **does** exit the `python` REPL. Rather than exiting, `gchi` reports *lexical error at character '\EOT'*.

How can I get `control-d` to properly exit the `ghci` REPL in emacs shell? Also, why does `ghci` work differently than `python`?

(And yes, `control-d` **does** exit `ghci` in a regular console window, just not for emacs `shell`.)

In the example below, I tried two variations of entering `control-d`. First, I tried just `control-d` which runs `comint-delchar-or-maybe-eof` from `shell-mode-map`. Then I tried the `control-q control-d` sequence to explicitly insert the `control-d` character, which then shows up as the ASCII character 4 and emacs displays as "^D". (However, the generic [box character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)) is shown if an actual character 4 is pasted into StackOverflow text form). Both variations fail in `ghci`.

First, the unsatisfactory behavior of `ghci`:

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 7.6.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Prelude> 

<interactive>:1:1: lexical error at character '\EOT'
Prelude> ^D

<interactive>:2:1: lexical error at character '\EOT'
Prelude> :quit
Leaving GHCi.
```

Next, the desired behavior of the `python` REPL:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Oct 26 2016, 20:30:19) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Oct 26 2016, 20:30:19) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> ^D

$ $
```

**Update**

I've installed the latest Haskell and still have the same issue ... now with Haskell 8.2.1:

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 8.2.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> 

<interactive>:1:1: error: lexical error at character '\EOT'
Prelude> ^D

<interactive>:2:1: error: lexical error at character '\EOT'
Prelude> :quit
Leaving GHCi.
```

Comment: I see the same behavior.  You should use `C-c C-d`/`M-x comint-send-eof` to send EOT instead of `C-q C-d`, but that doesn't work either.  ghci is clearly getting EOT, but isn't interpreting it correctly.  One difference is that TERM=dumb in shell-mode, but running `TERM=dumb ghci` still honors EOT in a normal terminal.  It might have something to do with this: https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/3256.

Comment: That ghc ticket overlaps a bit but I think is unrelated. But I do agree that TERM=dumb is a key issue. I also notice that certain command-line programs act weird in emacs whenever they use [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses). Dumb terminal doesn't play nice with ncurses. For instance, using the `swift` REPL in Ubuntu is weird in the emacs `shell` although the `swift` REPL is fine in the MacOS version of emacs. Overall, it would be nice if a REPL always had the option to turn of ncurses behavior.